# JQuery and PHP : add data to multiple divs in one AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've an HTML form where there are some checkboxes. Below this form, there is an empty div with id="area1" and an empty div with id="area2". They are to be filled with the data returned by a PHP function (actually, by now, only #area1 is filled).

To do so, I first retrieve with jQuery the values of the checkboxes (from 1 to n):

```
var value1 = $('#mybox1').prop('checked');
...
var valuen = $('#myboxn').prop('checked');
```

Then I pass the "valueX" variables to my PHP script using an AJAX call :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "process_function.php",
        data: { checkbox1 : value1 ... checkboxn : valuen},
        success: function(data){ 

        //add to div "area1" the retrieved data                     

        $('#area1').html(data);

        })
```

The AJAX call is triggered when a button is pressed.

Then process_function.php analyzes the data, and calls if necessary other functions located in a function.php file. Those functions always echo something.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that the results are concatenated to the same div : #area1 !

So I wonder if I can chose to what DIV add a given data. That is to say, within the same AJAX call, is there an "elegant" way to add some data to #area1 if value1 is checked, and to add other data to #area2 if value2 is checked, and to both areas if both values are checked, with only one PHP function ?

So far, the only idea I have is to create a jQuery function that tests if value1 is checked, then makes a call to process_function1.php, and so on for the other values. But it multiplicates the PHP functions.

Thanks

Comment: Return JSON. Parse, rinse, lather, repeat.

Comment: I agree with @JayBlanchard regardless of my answer below.  That is a slightly different answer to a slightly different question I'm guessing though!

Comment: Nope, same answer. If checkboxes are added and the JSON is parsed properly the OP could add those values to multiple content areas. One technique, many options.

Comment: I totally agree @JayBlanchard but I meant I don't think the OP quite knows what JSON is, how to return it, and how to parse it!  hence I meant we're perhaps leading the OP to start a slightly different question *How do I return JSON in PHP and then parse JSON in jQuery*

Comment: Aha @RobSchmuecker...I see!

Comment: I would not ask if I knew the solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could have your PHP script return a JSON object, which the jQuery `$.ajax` method will automatically translate into a Javascript object.

**PHP**

```
<?PHP

// example data. The key values will become part of the jscript object //
$data = ["div1" => "blahblahblah", "div2" => "<i>Something</i>"];

// need this for it to be recognized by jQuery as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({...}).done(function(data){
    $("#area1").html(data.div1);
    $("#area2").html(data.div2);
});
```

Comment: I have to change some code I wrote, but it seems to work fine ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP

// example data. The key values will become part of the jscript object //
$data = ["area1" => "blahblahblah", "area2" => "<i>Something</i>"];

// need this for it to be recognized by jQuery as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

echo json_encode($data);
```

Jquery Code

```
    $.ajax({...}).done(function(data){
       $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          $("#"+key).html(value);
    });

});
```

You may also use this code this is more dynamic.

Comment: as $data is to be filled by several functions, what is the best solution ? use it as a global var ?